# How to migrate my tables from my asp.net core app on linux

Tags: mysql, linux, asp.net-core

I have made an asp.net core app that runs perfectly in my windows machine. I need to deploy this app on a Linux machine. My problem comes when migrating my tables into MySQL server on the Linux machine. I have the Linux machine for production purposes and I need MySQL server for users handling. I have created a database but when I run the command dotnet ef database update to migrate my tables into this database I see the following error:

[image]

My connection string used for the connection to my database is the following :

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ElectransUsers;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

If I change the connection string writing localhost instead of localdb I see the following error:
[image]

If I remove mssqllocaldb I see the following error:

[image]
And my Configure method in the Startup.cs script is the following:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            //.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddSignalR();
    }
```

Does anyone know what I have to change in the connection string to be able to do the migration?
Thank you.

I have changed my conection string and code:

```
       services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
           options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"),
               mySqlOptions =>
               {
                   mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(10, 1, 38), Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure.ServerType.MySql); // replace with your Server Version and Type
               }));

"MysqlConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=ElectransUsers;User=root;Password=my_password;"
```

But I see the following error:

[image]

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a MySQL connection provider. Example code snippet here.

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
   options.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"),
       mySqlOptions =>
       {
        mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 1, 73), ServerType.MySql); // replace with your Server Version and Type
       })
```

My Connection String

```
 "MysqlConnection": "server=194.36.12.123;port=3306;database=database_name_here;uid=user_name_here;password=password_here"
```

I am using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` Package

Here is [documentation](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/master/README.md#getting-started)

Comment: Why use this? (I'm new to asp.net core development) Thanks, @Yigit Tanriverdi

Comment: The connection string is correct? @Yigit Tanriverdi

Comment: Where can I find documentation about this?

Comment: I added documentation link

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try it @Yigit Tanriverdi